# How can I fix a nested function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

```
% calculate the area of the circle
function a_circle = area(r)
a_circle=pi*r^2;
end

%calculate the volume of the cone
function v = vol(r,h)
v=0.333*area(r)*h;
end
```

in the above code, it is showing that the **vol(r,h)** is unused. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `area(r)` inside `vol(r, h)`:

```
%calculate the volume of the cone
function v = vol(r,h)
   % calculate the area of the circle
    function a_circle = area(r)
       a_circle=pi*r^2;
    end

    v=0.333*area(r)*h;
end
```

Comment: You can also define `area` after `vol`. The important thing to know is that the first function in the file is the public one, all the other ones are private.

Comment: Do it need to know object oriented programming for this case @CrisLuengo?

Comment: @NickPl: no, it has nothing to do with object-oriented programming. See [the documentation on function files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html): “Program files can contain multiple functions. If the file contains only function definitions, the first function is the main function, and is the function that MATLAB associates with the file name. Functions that follow the main function or script code are called local functions. Local functions are only available within the file.”

Comment: @NickPl: this answer suggests [nested functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html), which are a different beast.